# remove td that don't have an id using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have an HTML table containing labels and textboxes, in which few td's have id and few td's don't have an id. All other attributes are similar.The td's which don't have the id's are dynamically generated. The table structure looks something like below.

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td class = "myclass" id="sun">hello</td>
    <td class = "otherclass"><input type="text" class="wonder" id = "tone" readonly = "true"><td/>
    <td class = "myclass" id = "moon">my</td>
    <td class = "otherclass"><input type="text" class="wonder" id = "ttwo" readonly = "true"><td/>
     <td class = "myclass" id = "earth">name</td>
    <td class = "otherclass"><input type="text" class="wonder" id = "tthree" readonly = "true"><td/>
     <td class = "myclass">is</td>
    <td class = "otherclass"><input type="text" class="wonder" readonly = "true"><td/>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class ="myclass">mickey</td>
      <td class = "otherclass"><input type="text" class="wonder" readonly = "true"></td>
     <td class ="myclass" id = "stars">mouse</td>
     <td class = "otherclass"><input type = "text" class="wonder" id = "tfour" readonly = "true"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

On a button click, I want to remove the td's that don't have an id . I have tried the following.

```
$('#Reset').click(function(){  
    $('#myTable').find('tr td:not([id])').remove();
});
```

But this seems to remove the all the td's. I want to remove only those td's that don't have an id attribute. Can someone please help how this can be done.

Also please note that the table is dynamic and depending on the number of dynamic columns generated, the table structure changes everytime.

Comment: given that NONE of your tds have an `id`, why are you surprised that "remove all non-id tds" is doing exactly what you asked for? your ids are set on the `<input>` tags, not the `<td>`s

Comment: @Pranav C Balan : I have modified some part of the html.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `td` with `id`, if you want to remove `td` which contain input field that don't have an `id` then use

```js
$('#Reset').click(function() {
  $('#myTable').find('tr td input:not([id])').parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="myclass">hello</td>
    <td class="otherclass">
      <input type="text" class="wonder" id="tone" readonly="true">
    </td>
    <td class="myclass">my</td>
    <td class="otherclass">
      <input type="text" class="wonder" id="ttwo" readonly="true">
    </td>
    <td class="myclass">name</td>
    <td class="otherclass">
      <input type="text" class="wonder" id="tthree" readonly="true">
    </td>
    <td class="myclass">is</td>
    <td class="otherclass">
      <input type="text" class="wonder" readonly="true">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="myclass">mickey</td>
    <td class="otherclass">
      <input type="text" class="wonder" readonly="true">
    </td>
    <td class="myclass">mouse</td>
    <td class="otherclass">
      <input type="text" class="wonder" id="tfour" readonly="true">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="Reset">click
</button>
```